# Flavour violating muon decay

Tags: photons, leptons

Why is a muon decay into gamma and electron not possible?

Where/how does it violate the lepton flavour as muon and electron both have -1?

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton_number

Answer (score 2):

Flavour quantum numbers are routinely violated by weak interactions, but we can define a *generation* quantum number that is almost conserved. For example the number of first generation particles, i.e. number of electrons + number of electron neutrinos, is almost conserved. Likewise the number of muons + muon neutrinos and the number of taus + tau neutrinos.

I say *almost conserved* because neutrinos oscillate between the three neutrino flavours and this breaks the *generation* number conservation, but in most scattering events the probability of this happening is so tiny that it can be ignored.

And you can now see why $\mu \to e + \gamma$ is not allowed, because it changes the number of second and first generation particles present. For this to happen you would need something like:

1. $\mu \to \nu_\mu + W^-$
2. $W^- \to e + \bar \nu_e$
3. $\nu_\mu \to \nu_e$
4. $\nu_e + \bar\nu_e \to \gamma$

This is technically possible but the third step, i.e. the neutrino oscillation, is so improbable as to be effectively impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The decay from muon to electron need to happen via the weak nuclear force. The electromagnetic force does nto allow this decay. Hence, during such a decay it needs to radiate a boson of the weak nuclear force. Since the change is not changes (the muon and the electron both carry negative charge) the radiated boson needs to be the $Z_0$ boson, which is neutral. This boson is massive and unstable. So it will then decay into a pair of particles, typically two neutrinos. Since the $Z_0$ boson is neutral. It does not couple to the electromagnetic force. Hence no photon is radiated.